# Dual-boot fresh re-install ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

Ok guys, I have a dual booting laptop that has both windows 7 on it and ubuntu 14.04.
 I was messing around on ubuntu and did some stuff with the nvidia drivers that Im not quite sure how to fix.
I dont have any backups (lesson learned) and being that I havent had it very long dont have anything on there that is irreplaceable (a.k.a wiping it and then doing a clean install is perfectly fine with me).

So I was wondering how I would do a fresh install of ubuntu 14.04 without screwing up grub or my windows 7 partition.

All I want to do is wipe out the ubuntu side and re-install it back on there.
 Do I just go through the same process as dual booting or is there something special I must do now that I have some different partitons (the ubuntu one and the swap space) before I can re-install it?

Im still pretty new at this stuff so as detailed as possible is appreciated,
Thanks for all your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- first boot the live ubuntu 14.04
- then using gparted format the partation containing ubuntu
- then install the ubuntu 14.04 using [manual partitioning method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation).

Comment: So basically I just format the partiton where ubuntu currently resides and then just install it like I did the first time? (for dual-boot I had to partition manually and all that jazz as well)

Comment: yes its exactly like that,. you may use `sudo update-grub` when done

Comment: Do I format the swap partition as well, or does that matter?

Comment: its up to you, you may format the swap and create later or leave as it is..