# how to unmount a part of a single partition which is in used?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, boot-partition

I have **ubuntu 18.04** currently on my pc and some important docs on it. I want to install windows alongside my ubuntu.

as you know, to install windows we need a **primary NTFS Partition** for and first, we should unmount a part of the hard drive in order to install windows on it,

but I have a single partition. In case of a single partition, the Ubuntu system files will exist on this single partition and While you are operating Ubuntu, the system files will be in use. Thus, the Disk volume will be busy and A busy disk volume cannot be unmounted so The system cannot resize a mounted or busy disk.

Thus, we need some external factor to boot from and resize the single partition on which Ubuntu Operating System exists. after searching on the internet, For the purpose, I boot the computer from bootable Ubuntu Flash Drive and use **GParted** utility. but still, I can't resize the current partition and it is locked.

can anybody help me and had a good experience with this problem?

Comment: Probably it's still mounted, maybe because you just looked at it's contents after booting the live Ubuntu system (it got auto-mounted then). Unmount it and then try again to resize it with `gparted`.

Comment: How I can unmount it when it is locked? do you mean in Try Ubuntu mode?
i test it before :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct:

- You cannot make changes to any mounted partition.
- You cannot mount/unmount "part" of a partition.

The usual method around these hurdles is to make an Ubuntu LiveUSB. It's a bootable system that can run Gparted, and does not mount any partitions on your HDD. Use the "Try Ubuntu" environment to run GParted.

Comment: unfortunately, I tried this method but in Try Ubuntu, after running GParted, still I can't resize my partition and resize is locked.

Comment: If the partition is locked (key icon), that means the partition is mounted. [Unmount it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470698/how-to-unmount-a-partition-before-reinstallation).

Comment: If I unmount the whole partition, are my files on my hard drive lost?

Comment: Editing partitions is *inherently risky*. A botched re-partitioning can indeed destroy your Ubuntu system and lose all your files irretrievably. All of the folks whom I consider wise back up their data before starting the process. Merely mounting/unmounting does not affect your files in the slightest -- it merely affects your ability to access those files.

Comment: Unmount partition and only work(shrink) from right side(empty), need to have free space on partition to shrink it.  Windows will want about 50GBs or more, if you have that much free space and more you are good.  Make new NTFS partition for Windows.  Double and triple check everything before doing anything.  Should keep 15 to 20% free space in partitions at least.

Comment: I have enough space but my problem is that I can't unmount and resize my single partition. when I use bootable flash with ubuntu and use Gparted  in "Try ubuntu" mode, the unmount option is not active.

Comment: Ask yourself: If you are booted from a USB, then *why are any HDD partitions mounted in the first place?* In ordinary usage, they are not. When I boot from a USB, the HDD partitions are not mounted. You must be doing *something* that causes the HDD partition(s) to mount. We are not there, we cannot look over your shoulder.